# `A required class was missing while executing` maven plugin with GitHub action

Tags: maven, github-actions, maven-plugin

Recently my **GitHub actions** failed on specific maven goal complaining that **a required class (from plexus-utils) was missing**.

Everything worked well until now and still works well locally.

*(⚠ In my case this affects, `impsort-maven-plugin` but this can affect other maven-plugin, see answer to better understand)*

Here is the complete log for me ❌ :

```
Error:  

Failed to execute goal net.revelc.code:impsort-maven-plugin:1.6.2:check (default-cli) on project leshan-core: 
Execution default-cli of goal net.revelc.code:impsort-maven-plugin:1.6.2:check failed:
A required class was missing while executing net.revelc.code:impsort-maven-plugin:1.6.2:check:
org/codehaus/plexus/util/DirectoryScanner

Error:  -----------------------------------------------------
Error:  realm =    plugin>net.revelc.code:impsort-maven-plugin:1.6.2
Error:  strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
Error:  urls[0] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/net/revelc/code/impsort-maven-plugin/1.6.2/impsort-maven-plugin-1.6.2.jar
Error:  urls[1] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/com/github/javaparser/javaparser-core/3.22.1/javaparser-core-3.22.1.jar
Error:  urls[2] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/30.1.1-jre/guava-30.1.1-jre.jar
Error:  urls[3] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
Error:  urls[4] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar
Error:  urls[5] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar
Error:  urls[6] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.8.0/checker-qual-3.8.0.jar
Error:  urls[7] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.5.1/error_prone_annotations-2.5.1.jar
Error:  urls[8] = file:/home/runner/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
Error:  Number of foreign imports: 1
Error:  import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-core:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
Error:  
Error:  -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner
Error:  -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems this happens because :

1. Since recently default **GitHub image runner** are now using `maven 3.9.0` (see [runner-images#7216](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7216))
2. **Maven 3.9.0** remove backward compatibility dependency to `plexus-utils` (see [maven-3.9.0/release-notes](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.0/release-notes.html#potentially-breaking-core-changes))
3. **impsort-maven-plugin** does NOT declares COMPILE dependency on `plexus-utils` (see [impsort-maven-plugin#64](https://github.com/revelc/impsort-maven-plugin/issues/64))

This problem could be faced with other maven-plugin.
If you face it, you can do  waiting plugin maintainer fix this :

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.revelc.code</groupId>
  <artifactId>impsort-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

(More details at [runner-images#7216-issuecomment-1455954873](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7216#issuecomment-1455954873))

Comment: If you are a plugin author then good to stop using plexus-utils FileUtils and add maven-shared-utils as an explicit dependency in the plugin pom.xml. maven-shared-utils has a drop-in replacement for FileUtils.getFiles for example.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively – and to be independent from the runner's Maven version – you can use a [Maven Wrapper](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/):

> The Maven Wrapper is an easy way to ensure a user of your Maven build has everything necessary to run your Maven build.
>
> *Why might this be necessary?* Maven to date has been very stable for users, is available on most systems or is easy to procure: but with many of the recent changes in Maven it will be easier for users to have a fully encapsulated build setup provided by the project. With the Maven Wrapper, this is very easy to do and it's a great idea and initial implementation borrowed from Gradle.

To e.g. downgrade to Maven 3.8.8:

```
mvn wrapper:wrapper -Dmaven=3.8.8
```

Afterwards, replace "mvn" with "./mvnw" in your workflows.